# Internet Explorer (W2k16) takes 2 minutes to load website

Tags: windows-server-2016, internet-explorer-11

Today, one of our suppliers installed a Windows 2016 server for us, and provided us with the required privileges to access the server. On this freshly installed (updates & patches installed) machine, we encounter the following issue:

After opening Internet Explorer 11 (default page `about:blank`), we type in a URL of a random website and it takes the browser about **2 minutes** to load the website. As long as we stay within the same Tab of IE, and within the same website domain (i.e. google.com), the follow-up pages all load quickly and without any problem. However, if we dare to switch to a new tab (or even open a link in a new tab), or we go to a new website domain (i.e. microsoft.com), it again takes 2 minutes to load the initial website.

Looking at the F12 network console, we see a response time of less then 100 ms, but this only shows AFTER the 2 minutes have passed and the website has loaded. Also, there are no certificate issues, and in our firewall we see that the HTTP(S) requests are leaving the server as soon we we hit the navigate button. Also there are no errors in the F12 Console view.

To try and troubleshoot, we also tried putting IE11 into Emulation mode for IE10 or IE9, but this has not helped us. It also happens for **both internal and external websites**, and ping/nslookup/tracert all work fine and show no weird results.

Any fixes, or suggestions on troubleshooting the issue?
Thanks ahead,

Comment: Run a packet capture on the server while you're running a test and see what the capture shows.

Comment: Wireshark shows a lot of TCP retransmissions to Fortinet systems. We have asked the team that manages the Fortinet systems to check what is going on, on their end.

Comment: Disable SmartScreen (windows defender) completely and try again ...